# Consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

From wikipedia's page on the Hahn-Banach Theorem:

If $V$ is a normed vector space with linear subspace $U$ (not necessarily closed) and if $z$ is an element of $V$ not in the closure of $U$, then there exists a continuous linear map $ψ : V → K$ with $ψ(x) = 0$ for all $x$ in $U$, $ψ(z) = 1$, and $||ψ|| = dist(z, U)^{−1}.$

How is this a consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that

$$p \colon x \mapsto \operatorname{dist}(x,U)$$

is a sublinear functional. (It's a seminorm, actually.)

Then apply the Hahn-Banach extension theorem to $\tilde{p} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{dist}(z,U)}\cdot p$, and the linear map $t\cdot z \mapsto t$ from the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $z$ to the scalar field.

Alternatively, let $W = z - \overline{U}$, and $C = B_{\operatorname{dist}(z,U)}(0)$. Then $W$ and $C$ are disjoint convex sets, and $C$ is open and balanced. By one of the Hahn-Banach separation theorems, there is a continuous linear functional $\psi_0 \colon V \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\lvert \psi_0(x)\rvert < 1$ for all $x\in C$ and $\psi_0(y) = 1$ for all $y \in W$. These conditions show $\lVert \psi_0\rVert = \operatorname{dist}(z,U)^{-1}$ and $\psi_0(z) = 1$. If the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$, let $\psi = \psi_0$, if the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$, let $\psi$ the continuous linear form with real part $\psi_0$, that is, $\psi(x) = \psi_0(x) - i \psi_0(ix)$ for all $x\in V$.

Comment: Hi. Could you explain "Then apply the Hahn-Banach extension theorem to $\tilde{p} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{dist}(z,U)}\cdot p$, and the linear map $t\cdot z \mapsto t$ from the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $z$ to the scalar field."? What is the linear functional that you're taking? $t$? and what is the sublinear that you're taking? $\bar{p}$?

Comment: It seems like $\bar{p}=1$?

Comment: @Teodorism The sublinear functional is a constant multiple of $p$, the scaling factor chosen such that $\tilde{p}(z) = 1$. That is, of course, $\tilde{p}(x) = p(x)/p(z)$ for all $x \in V$ (since $z \notin \overline{U}$ we have $p(z) = \operatorname{dist}(z,U) > 0$, so we can divide). The linear functional on $M = K\cdot z = \{tz : t \in K\}$ is $f(tz) = t$. Then $f(z) = f(1\cdot z) = 1$, and $f(tz) = t \leqslant \lvert t\rvert = \tilde{p}(tz)$, so the hypotheses of the extension lemma are satisfied.

Comment: Is $z$ fixed? What is the domain of $\bar{p}$?

Comment: Yes, $z$ is a given point in $V \setminus \overline{U}$. The domain of $\tilde{p}$ is $V$.

Comment: If $z$ is a given point then $\bar{p}$ changes for each $z$. Shouldn't the sublinear be defined on $V$ only independent of $z$?

Comment: $z$ doesn't change. It is a given point. Arbitrary (subject to the condition of not being in $\overline{U}$), but once it has been selected, it is one fixed unchanging point for the whole construction.

Comment: Ahhh. I see now thanks. BTW, I am trying to solve the same problem but the book I'm reading says take $U+\mathcal{R}z$ as the subspace for $f$. Do you know why?

Comment: Here it doesn't matter because the sublinear functional used vanishes on $U$, so any extension of my $f$ that is dominated by $\tilde{p}$ automatically vanishes on $U$. But in more general situations one can use sublinear functionals which don't vanish identically on the subspace in question, and then one may have to start with a domain including $U$ to guarantee that the extension vanishes on $U$. So taking $U + K\cdot z$ as a starting point also in this case has an advantage of uniformity.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Let $d:= \inf \{||x-z||: x \in U\}   (= dist(z,U))$. Then $d>0$.

Let $E$ be the linear span of $ \{z\} \cup U$ and define $h:E \to K$ by

$$h(\alpha z+u)= \alpha d.$$

Then $h(u)=0$ for all $u \in U$ and $h(z)=d$.

2. Now show that $h$ is continuous and linear and that $||h||=1$
3. By the  the Hahn-Banach Theorem there is  a continuous linear map $f:V \to K$ with

$f(u)=0$ for all $u \in U$, $f(z)=d$ and $||f||=1$.

4. Now take $ \psi:=\frac{1}{d}f$

Comment: Aren't $d$ and $h$ sublinear?

Comment: $d$ is a number ! $h$ is linear .

Comment: @Fred How can I show $\|h\|=1$?  I think it's the main difficulty.