# Intersection of kernels which contains a subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. Assume $Y\subset X$ is a linear subspace of $X$. Prove that 
$$\overline{Y}=\bigcap_{f\in X^*,\mathrm{ker}f\supset Y}\mathrm{ker}f$$

I was able to prove that $\overline{Y}\subseteq\bigcap_{f\in X^*,\mathrm{ker}f\supset Y}\mathrm{ker}f$. However, I couldn't find a way to show the converse.

***My attempt***:
Obviously, a direct way to attack the problem it would be consider a $y\in \cap_{f\in X^*,\mathrm{ker}f\supset Y}\mathrm{ker}f$ and construct a sequence of $\{y_n\}_n\subset Y$ such that $y_n\rightarrow y$ in norm. I was thinking in the following identity $$\lvert\lvert y_n-y\rvert\rvert=\sup_{f\in X^*,\lvert\lvert f\rvert\rvert\leq1}|f(y_n-y)|.$$
Since the qualities of $y$ are stated in terms of bounded functionals, but my attempt was unfruitful.

Is there any suggestion or hint to approach the exercise?

Comment: I would say this is an application of Hahn-banach. See the second important consequence [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem).

Comment: @AndresMejia, I was thinking the same thing. Basically, the identity written above is a direct consequence of Hahn-Banach. But I couldn't find the right application of H-B. Thanks for your comment, it was quite useful.

Comment: Let  $w \in V \setminus \overline{Y}$. There exists a linear functional that vanishes on $Y$ and $f(w)=1 \notin \ker f$, which implies that intersecting over all these kernels leaves just $\overline{Y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer.

Using the [second importance consequence on Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem) we see that for each $w \in V \setminus \overline{Y}$. There exists a linear functional that vanishes on $Y$ and $f(w)=1 \notin \ker f$, which implies that $w \notin \bigcap \ker f$. Hence, it follows that their intersection is contained in the closure of $Y$.

---

On SE, the second consequence is proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025803/consequence-of-the-hahn-banach-theorem).

Comment: I was about to tell you to post an answer. But you were faster.

Comment: @DonQuixote haha I was sitting and thinking about it, it's been a while since I've dealt with the material so I wanted to make sure there weren't stupid mistakes before I posted an answer.