# An application of Hahn-Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand the Hahn-Banach Theorem by solving the following problem.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $Y$ be a linear subspace of $X$, and $z \in X \setminus Y$ such that
$$d = dist(z, Y ) = \inf_{y \in Y}\| y − z\| > 0.$$
Prove that there exists $f ∈ X^∗$ such that $\|f \| ≤ 1, f(z) = d,   f(y) = 0 $ for all $y \in Y$.

My questions is, can I argue that because  $Z:=X\setminus Y $ is a subspace of $X$ and because $d\in Z^*$, then by HBT $f|_{Z}=d$? How do I conclude $\|f\|\leq 1$?

Comment: $Z=X\setminus Y$ does not contain $0$ and hence is not a vector space

Comment: You are right but $d$ is only defined over $Z$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consequence of the Hahn-Banach Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025803/consequence-of-the-hahn-banach-theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction is that $f:\text{span}(Y\cup\{z\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ with $f(y+\alpha z)=\alpha d.$ Note that every element in $\text{span}(Y\cup\{z\})$ can be represented by $y+\alpha z$ in a unique way.

For any $y+\alpha z\in\text{span}(Y\cup\{z\})$, if $\alpha\ne 0$, then $-(1/\alpha)y\in Y$ and hence $d\leq\|-(1/\alpha)y-z\|$, 
\begin{align*}
|f(y+\alpha z)|\leq|\alpha|\|-(1/\alpha)y-z\|=\|-y-\alpha z\|=\|y+\alpha z\|,
\end{align*}
so $\|f\|\leq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how to show $\|f\|\leq 1$? I'm only stuck on that.

Comment: I have shown that.